# Mac OS Big Sur 11.7 completely drops network stack when writing to SMB share

Tags: macos, file-sharing, smb, macos-bigsur

I have an SMB file share (Windows 10 PC) that I connect to with my M1 MacBook Pro running BigSur 11.7. Since last week every time I connect to the SMB and initiate copy writing to the share, the Finder will freeze and all of the networking stack for both WiFi and Ethernet will stop working.

They show as connected but no ping, no internet connectivity (browser is not frozen). Toggle the networks On/Off doesn’t help - I must reboot and everything works fine until I try to write to the SMB again.

Connecting and reading from the SMB share is fine. i.e. I can open files stored there or **copy to my Mac** just fine. But copy from the Mac to the share will cause the hang.

My wife has the same MacBook Pro and it all works fine on hers, so the server/share config is fine.

As I was experimenting I noticed I can write small file to the SMB just fine - anything under 20MB worked. When I went over 100MB - the hang occurs.

I don't want to reinstall, unless I really, really have. Any pointers to help, please?

Nothing in logs.

**UPDATE**: Here are the first 1,000 lines from [the Path Finder crash report on PasteBi](https://pastebin.com/bYXXfqX4)n.

Comment: Nothing in the logs? Not even in the kernel logs (`dmesg`)?

Comment: Really nothing related to a crash, networking or anything. If I use Path Finder instead fo Finder I can get the crash report - added.

Comment: As I was experimenting I noticed I can write small file to the SMB just fine - anything under 20MB worked. When I went over 100MB - the hang occurs.